# one-to-many relation ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have two tables:

```
class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "applicant"
  belongs_to :specialization, :foreign_key => "id"
end

class Specialization < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "specialization"
  has_many :applicant, :foreign_key => "id"
end
```

I'm trying to get the total count of applicants pr specialization. In SQL that would be something like this:

```
SELECT a.Name, COALESCE(b.total,0) AS "Total Applicants"
FROM specialization AS a
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT specialization.Name, COUNT(*) as total
                FROM applicant
        JOIN specialization ON applicant.specialization = specialization.id
        GROUP BY specialization.name) AS b
ON a.name = b.name
ORDER BY a.name;
```

How do I do this with RoR? So far what I've tried is:

```
<% Specialization.includes(:applicant).all.each do |s| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= s.name%></td>
        <td><%= s.applicant.count()%></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

This doesn't seem to work though since I'm only counting 1 applicant at some of the specializations where I know from looking at my database that there are 4 applicants at some specializations.

EDIT:
It's a pg SQL database and the create table commands from the SQL file is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Specialization (
    Id  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name    TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Applicant (
    Id              SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName       TEXT,
    MiddleInitial   TEXT,
    LastName        TEXT,
    Specialization  INTEGER REFERENCES Specialization (id) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: `belongs_to :specialization, :foreign_key => "id"` -- this is very strange and unusual. How does the distinguishing column act like the foreign key for some association? Consider revision of your models.

Comment: I the PK part from both tables now. Still doesn't work though. I have to call them id since that is what they are called in my database.